# How to set an an active class to a variable - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

My first question on S.O. let's see how it goes.

I'm trying to set the "active class" to a variable in my Home.js, and pass down the value, as a prop to my `<Buddy />` component. Once there I will set that to an integer to decide what slide my [text carousel](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) goes to. I'll figure out that part (but if you know, spare me the time).

I'm using an npm package [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) to scroll to that component once clicked. Then the component is set to "active". I will drop some code.

1. Nav bar section in the Home.js component..

```
return (
<div className="navBar">

   <div className="navItem">
        <Link
           activeClass='active'
           to="home"
           spy={true}
           smooth={true}
           offset={0}
           className='nav-Link'>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </Link>
    </div>
       
    <div className="navItem">
       <Link
           activeClass='active'
           to="projects"
           spy={true}
           smooth={true}
           offset={0}
           className='nav-Link'>
               Projects
        </Link>
     </div>
       
     <div className="navItem">
       <Link
           activeClass='active'
           to="mission"
           spy={true}
           smooth={true}
           offset={0}
           className='nav-Link'>
               Mission
        </Link>
      </div>
       
     <div className="navItem">
       <Link
           activeClass='active'
           to="about"
           spy={true}
           smooth={true}
           offset={0}
           className='nav-Link'>
               About
        </Link>
     </div>
       
     <div className="navBar">
       <Link
           activeClass='active'
           to="contact"
           spy={true}
           smooth={true}
           offset={0}
           className='nav-Link'>
               Contact
        </Link>
     </div>

</div>
```

2. My  component sitting right beneath.

```
<Buddy />
```

3. Each component on my SPA/Portfolio has an `id` that the  on my nav bar looks to go to.

```
//Projects.js

const Projects = () => {
    return (
        <div className="projectsComponent" id="projects">
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

So when it scrolls to the component, it sets that div? or component? to active.

```
// back in Home.js

<div className="navItem">
        <Link
            activeClass='active' <-----------
            to="projects"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={0}
            className='nav-Link'>
                Projects
            </Link>
        </div>
```

I just want to set whatever I need to, into a variable in `Home.js` to pass down as a prop to `<Buddy />`. Thanks, guys! Remember it's my first question ever! Be nice!

** If you have a better idea, like when the scroll reaches that component, set the index of my carousel to 1,2,3.. let me know too. Thanks

*** I will also include my `<SpeechCarousel />` component here. It lives in my `<Buddy />` component and ill pass another prop to it. Thanks again.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
import "../styles/css/Buddy.css"

const SpeechCarousel = () => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  
    const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
      setIndex(selectedIndex);
    };

    return (
        <div id="carousel2">
      <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} interval={null}>
        
        <Carousel.Item className="car2item">
          <p>TEXT</p>
        </Carousel.Item>

        <Carousel.Item className="car2item">
        <p>TEXT</p>
        </Carousel.Item>

        <Carousel.Item className="car2item">
        <p>TEXT</p>
        </Carousel.Item>

        <Carousel.Item className="car2item">
        <p>TEXT</p>
        </Carousel.Item>

        <Carousel.Item className="car2item">
        <p>TEXT</p>
        </Carousel.Item>

     </Carousel>

      </div>
    )
}
export default SpeechCarousel;
```